# Calculate forward direction vector using 2 vectors

Tags: vectors

I have 2 vectors:

a(1,2,5) and b(-5,8,1)

I need to calculate the forward direction vector from vector A to vector B.

How do I do this? Is there a formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The direction vector from vector **a** to vector **b** can be calculated as followed:

$$\overrightarrow{AB}=\overrightarrow{OB}-\overrightarrow{OA}$$

In this case:

$\overrightarrow{AB}=\begin{pmatrix}-5\\8\\1\end{pmatrix}-\begin{pmatrix}1\\2\\5\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-6\\6\\-4\end{pmatrix}$

So the direction vector from $a$ to $b$ is $\overrightarrow{AB}=\begin{pmatrix}-6\\6\\-4\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: You said its B - A yet in the illustration you calculated A - B

Comment: Edited. Thanks :)